# MaterialUI stepper use alternative color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the colour that a material ui Stepper uses? By default the material UI stepper's icons use the primary colour for the "active" as well as "completed" steps.

```
class HorizontalLinearStepper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeStep: 1,
    skipped: new Set()
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const steps = getSteps();
    const { activeStep } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
          {steps.map((label, index) => {
            const props = {};
            const labelProps = {};
            return (
              <Step key={label} {...props}>
                <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
              </Step>
            );
          })}
        </Stepper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now the stepper uses the theme's main colour as "icon colour". How can I change this to use the secondary colour instead? Adding a `color` props to any of the `Stepper`, `Step` or `StepLabel` doesn't seem to work, neither does `style={{color: 'red', backgroundColor: 'red'}}` give the expected results in any of those things.

How can I modify the colour?

A fiddle can be found [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5vpw3yzpm)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `StepIconProps` prop on `StepLabel` to customise the classes and change the colour e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/k1wp19vz6o